# Android: downloading huge volume data from Parse.com

Tags: android, database, download, parse-platform, progressdialog

I am working on downloading data (some long messages in String) from Parse.com.

While the code works previously when the data volume is small, now when the database is growing bigger, for weaker device, the download process will be failed. The codes are as follows:

### Codes:

```
// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class DownloadRemoteDataTask_message extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();            
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CopyOfFirst2.this);    
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait!");                                 
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Updating database...");                 
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);      
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {            
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("MessagesDB");
            query.whereEqualTo("status", "accepted");
            query.setLimit((total_message_be_dl+1));
            query.orderByDescending("qref_message");

            try 
            {
                ob_message = query.find();
            } 
            catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {           
            for (ParseObject parse_table : ob_message)
            {
                String t_objectID = parse_table.getObjectId();
                String t_status = (String) parse_table.get("status");
                String t_user = (String) parse_table.get("username");
                String t_source = (String) parse_table.get("source");
                String t_title= (String) parse_table.get("title");
                int t_qref_canton = (Integer) parse_table.get("qref_canton");
                String t_canton = (String) parse_table.get("canton");
                int t_qref_message = (Integer) parse_table.get("qref_message");
                String t_message = (String) parse_table.get("message");

                String St_qref_canton = String.valueOf(t_qref_canton);
                String St_qref_message = "C"+String.valueOf(t_qref_message);

                String conso =
                          t_objectID        + "----\n"              //0        
                        + t_status          + "----\n"              //1 
                        + t_user            + "----\n"              //2
                        + t_source          + "----\n"              //3
                        + t_title           + "----\n"              //4
                        + t_qref_canton     + "----\n"              //5
                        + t_canton          + "----\n"              //6
                        + t_qref_message    + "----\n"              //7
                        + t_message         + "----\n"              //8
                        ;           

                SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
                e.putString(St_qref_message,conso);
                e.commit();
            }             
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            custom_dialog(total_message_be_dl);
        }
    }
```

## Question:

The ProgressDialog stops running (before the process end?), it freezes for a while for both stronger and weaker device.

But for stronger device, around 7 to 8 seconds the custom_dialog pops with a successful message counting the total message downloaded.

But for weaker device, it just black out afterwards.

The messages volume up till now is around 600 messages (with chinese and english characters), and is believed that the volume will + 10 messages daily.

The data downloaded will be stored as SharedPrefrenece only instead of local database in view of simple nature with reference to a unique key (qref xxx),

How could the above codes be improved? Or how can make the progressDialog not to disappear too quickly until all works are completed?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by stronger or weaker device. The shared preference storage might be getting constrained in the weaker device. Another piece of advice may be to move your e.commit() message outside the for loop to minimize commits. That should improve performance. Lastly, and this depends more on your use case, have you looked into Parse Local Datastore - https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pinning? That may help if you're interested in offline support.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice! I have moved out the e.commit() outside the loop, this really significantly improved performance!! thanks a lot! it will be highly appreciated if you can make it as an answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences.Editor editor; method **commit() is an expensive operation**.

It's call should definitely be **minimized**. You can **call it once inside onPause()** of your activity to ensure all your operations are updated.

For more details:
http://typorrhea.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/android-sharedpreferences-edit-commit-is-expensive/